# Overflow auto inside a div not working in ie

Tags: html, css, overflow

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/FbC86/. If you open this page with Chrome or Firefox the text inside the cell is overflowing correctly through a vertical scrollbar. If you open it with Internet explorer it doesn't work properly.

I need your advice as i am new to web development and i cannot find any solution to this problem. Thanks in advance!
Part of the code:

CSS

```
div.main
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
div.transparent{
    padding:3em;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
...
<td colspan="7" valign="top"  style="height:0;" >
    <div class="main">
    <div class="transparent">
Here goes a long text
</div</div></td>
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `height` attribute to the div you want to overflow.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FbC86/1/)